# Clang++ makes linker fail on template classes (but it works with g++)

Tags: c++, linker-errors, clang++, explicit-instantiation

I have a program that works nicely with GCC, but compiling it with Clang instead makes the linker fail.

I think my issue is with template classes, so I implemented this small example.

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "Point.h"

int main()
{
    Point<int> p1;
    Point<int> p2{ 3, 6 };
}
```

`Point.h`:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

template<typename T>
class Point {
    T x, y;
  public:
    Point();
    Point(T, T);
};

template class Point<int>;
template class Point<float>;

#endif
```

`Point.cpp`:

```
#include "Point.h"

template<typename T>
Point<T>::Point()
    : x{0}, y{0}
{}

template<typename T>
Point<T>::Point(T t_x, T t_y)
    : x{t_x}, y{t_y}
{}
```

When I build it with `g++ Point.cpp test.cpp`, it works without a problem.

But with Clang, it gives the following errors:

```
$ clang++ Point.cpp test.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-8ab886.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Point<int>::Point()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `Point<int>::Point(int, int)'
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Or, using lld:

```
$ clang++ -fuse-ld=lld Point.cpp test.cpp
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: Point<int>::Point()
>>> referenced by test.cpp
>>>               /tmp/test-f95759.o:(main)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: Point<int>::Point(int, int)
>>> referenced by test.cpp
>>>               /tmp/test-f95759.o:(main)
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I guess my explicit instantiations in `Point.h` aren't good enough for Clang, but I can't figure what it wants.

Comment: According to this answer, gcc's behavior seems to be wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151901/why-does-position-of-explicit-template-instantiation-matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your explicit instantiation should be where definitions are visible, so at the end of Points.cpp

From [class_template#Explicit_instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation):

> An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the class, struct, or union they refer to. It may appear in the program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the entire program, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Sure, but why does gcc generate the definitions?

Comment: @cigien: end of TU is a valid point of instantiation, so it should succeed for Points.cpp and fails for test.cpp, so probably breaks ODR.

Comment: Ah, so the program doesn't technically need to be diagnosed?

Comment: @cigien: Mostly the case with template. and it is my understanding from quote from cpp reference.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to be a reasonable interpretation.